# Como traer informacion con ajax a un formulario?

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Estoy intentando hacer un CRUD en codeigniter, pero a la hora de traer la información no encuentro la manera de que se almacene en el input del formulario (el formulario está en un modal).

Éste es el código del model:

```
 public function carga_edit_client($cedula_rif){
    //se generan las consultas

    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('clientes');
    $this->db->where('cedula_rif',$cedula_rif);
    $consulta=$this->db->get();
    //se retorna la variable $consulta en un arreglo(->result())
    return $consulta->result();
}
```

Este es el codigo del controller:

```
  //funcion para mostar informacion de los clientes en el datatable
public function show_client(){
    //se define un arreglo con la informacion de los clientes
    $consulta=array('data'=>$this->Clientes_model->show_client());

    if(!$consulta){
        die('Error');
    }else{
        //se codifica la data en formato json
        echo json_encode($consulta);
    }
}
```

Codigo del javascript:

```
      //function que muestra la informacion a editar
  $("#modal_editar").on("click" ,function(){

    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',

      url:'http://localhost/Proyectos/Quantum/index.php/clientes/carga_edit_client',

      success:function(data){


        //$("#apellido_cliente").val(datos.apellido_cliente);
        //console.log(data);

        //hacer que muestre la informacion


      }
    })//end ajax


  })//end function onclick
```

Codigo de HTML:

```
    <!-- Modal Agregar-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_agregar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal_eliminar_label">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" >Agregar Cliente</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <section id="contact" class="four">
              <div class="container">
                <!--Formulario-->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                    <form class="form-horizontal " >
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="cedula_rif" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Cedula</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 "><input  id="cedula_rif" name="cedula_rif" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Cedula o Rif" required="required" autofocus></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="nombre_cliente" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Nombres</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6"><input id="nombre_cliente" name="nombre_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombres" required="required"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="apellido_cliente" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Apellidos</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6"><input id="apellido_cliente" name="apellido_cliente" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos" required="required"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="direccion_domicilio" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Dirección de domicilio</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6"><input id="direccion_domicilio" name="direccion_domicilio" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Dirección de domicilio" ></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="direccion_empresa" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Direccion de empresa</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6"><input id="direccion_empresa" name="direccion_empresa" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Direccion de empresa" ></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="telefono_local" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Telefono local</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6"><input id="telefono_local" name="telefono_local" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono local" ></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="telefono_empresa" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Telefono de empresa</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6"><input id="telefono_empresa" name="telefono_empresa" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono empresa" ></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="telefono_celular" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Telefono celular</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6"><input id="telefono_celular" name="telefono_celular" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono celular" ></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email_cliente" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Correo electronico</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6"><input id="email_cliente" name="email_cliente" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo electronico" ></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="tipo" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Tipo</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <select id="id_tipo" name="id_tipo"  class="form-control" >
                            <option value="1">Cliente</option>
                            <option value="2">Proveedor</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-11">
                          <button id="btn_agregar_cliente" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "  value="Guardar">Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </form><!--End form class_horizontal-->
                  </div>
                </div><!--End row form-->

              </div>
            </section><!--End section-->


          </div><!--End modal-body-->
          <div class="modal-footer">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End Modal Agregar-->
 </form><!-- End agregar-->
</div><!-- End div-->
```

Comment: ¿y lo que se obtiene en `data` es un array con los datos, exactamente lo que se quiere mostrar en el input? ¿La idea es mostrar sólo en `#apellido_cliente` o en todos? ¿Como se está relacionando los daños de la consulta con cada input donde debería ir?

Comment: ¿En `JS` la variable `data`, es un `object` o un `string`? No veo que indiques al `ajax` el [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: hola mariano, si, lo que se obtiene en data es un array con los datos y lo quiero mostrar en todos los input del formulario, claro cada uno con su respectiva informacion.

Comment: Como estas Marcos, ya especifique el tipo de dato  que se obtiene , le coloque dataType : 'json' , y aun nada ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo tienes en como capturas la data del ajax, porque viene una variable llamada data y tu colocaste datos.apellido_cliente. Eso debería de solucionar tu problema.

```
//function que muestra la informacion a editar
  $("#modal_editar").on("click" ,function(){
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
url:'http://localhost/Proyectos/Quantum/index.php/clientes/carga_edit_client',
      success:function(data){
        $("#apellido_cliente").val(data.apellido_cliente);
        //console.log(data);
   //hacer que muestre la informacion
      }
    })//end ajax
  })//end function onclick
```

Si quieres agregar los otros datos, simplemente colocas los otros campos con su respectivo valor del json y listo.

Si eso no lo soluciona verifica el nombre de la columna en la db.

Prueba y cuéntanos q tal.

Pd: estoy desde el celular, disculpen la poca ética de la respuesta.

Comment: Buenos días Pablo, le cambie datos por data, y aun nada, ya verifique la base de datos... Gracias de igual manera seguire buscando haber que puede ser

Comment: Q navegador usas? Si usas Chrome puedes revisar cómo trae el json y si es q lo está trayendo.